# Create array from many variables

Tags: arrays, bash

Using `bash` I am trying to create an `echo` command with a list of variables. The number of variables can differ on what I am trying to do but I know how many I have as I count them in `$ctr1`. An example of what it should look like is:

```
echo "$var1,$var2,$var3"
```

etc. with the last variable the same number as the counter.

Can someone give me an idea as to what I should be doing, an example would be great. I know it could be done with `if` statements with a line for the possible number in the counter but that is not practical as there can be from 1 to 50+ variables in a line. I do not know if this should be an array or such like nor how to put this together. Any assistance on this would be a help.

Comment: Helping you : http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/

Comment: Can the variable names also differ ? or will they always be like var1, var2 .... ?

Comment: "_I do not know if this should be an array or such like_" Probably yes.  To give you a better answer, you need to explain where the variables are coming from.

Comment: As @John1024 said, knowing where the variables are coming from can help; for instance, if they are coming from the command line into a shell script, you could do something similar to the following: `val=; for var in "$@"; do val="${val},${var}"; done; echo "${val},$#"`, then doing something like `test.sh a b c d e` would output `,a,b,c,d,e,5` (an extra `,` yeah, but where the variables are coming from might eliminate this, or change the loop completely).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this should be an [array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) instead.

Instead of doing e.g.

```
var1=foo
var2=bar
var3=quux
ctr1=3
echo "${var1},${var2},${var3}"
```

you could do

```
var=("foo" "bar" "quux")
( IFS=,; echo "${var[*]}" )
```

Example:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

# the following is equivalent to doing
#  ( IFS=,; echo "$*" )
# but that wouldn't be a good example, would it?

for argument in "$@"; do
    var+=( "${argument}" )
done
( IFS=,; echo "${var[*]}" )
```

.

```
$ ./test.sh foo
foo

$ ./test.sh foo bar
foo,bar

$ ./test.sh foo bar "qu ux"
foo,bar,qu ux
```